# Number of cosets by quaternion order

Tags: dirichlet-series, quaternion-algebras

Let $D$ be a quaternion division algebra over $\mathbb Q$ and let $\Lambda\subset D$ be a maximal order.
For $n\in\mathbb Z$ let $\Lambda^{(n)}$ denote the set of all $\lambda\in\Lambda$ with reduced norm $n$. Then $\Lambda^{(1)}$ is a multiplicative group acting on $\Lambda^{(n)}$.
Is there a nice closed formula for the numbers
$$
a_n=\big| \Lambda^{(1)}\ \big\backslash\Lambda^{(n)}\ \big|?
$$
or $b_n=a_n+a_{-n}$?

Is  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b_n}{n^s}$ a known Dirichlet series?

Comment: The Dirichlet series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s}$ should be very close to the Dirichlet series $\sum_X |\Lambda/X|^{-s}$, where the $X$'s are the finite index left ideals of $\Lambda$ that are isomorphic to $\Lambda$. This zeta function, and generalisations thereof, have been well-studied. I hope you find the following reference (or the references therein) useful: 'Analytic continuation of partial zeta functions of arithmetic orders' by Bushnell and Reiner, 1984.

Comment: @eloiprime: Can you tell, how is this related? I am modding out a multiplicative group action here, not an ideal, or an additive subgroup?

Comment: Let's define a function $f:\Lambda\to\{\text{principal left ideals of $\Lambda$}\}$ as follows. For each $x\in\Lambda$, put $f(x)=\Lambda x$. Note that if $u$ is a unit in $\Lambda$, then, for any $x\in\Lambda$, we have $f(ux)=\Lambda(ux)=(\Lambda u )x=\Lambda x=f(x)$. It follows that $f$ induces a function from the orbit space, $\overline{f}:\Lambda^{(1)} \backslash \Lambda\to\{\text{principal left ideals of $\Lambda$}\}$. In fact, $\overline{f}$ is a bijection. Now, compute the image of the orbit space $\Lambda^{(1)}\backslash\Lambda^{\pm(n)}$ under $\overline{f}$.

Comment: @eloiprime: Great, thanks!